# Is there a way to plot multiple levels variables in R in separate graph with a simple code?

Tags: r, plot, levels

I wonder if somebody knows how to execute this code, but that each level is separately plotted.

```
sites<-levels(OrchardSprays$treatment)
par(mfcol=c(4,2))
for (i in 1:length(sites)) {
  here_tmp<-sites[i]
  plot(droplevels(subset(OrchardSprays, Site = here_tmp, select = c(treatment,decrease))))
  }
```

[image: this is the output of the code, but they are all the same. I want to print different graphics with each level in treatment]

This is the output that it gives me. But I want different graphs of the different levels. I don't know why it gives me the same graphs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @SimonG that it's not clear why you'd want to have the each level plotted on a separate graph, but here's a way to do it with `ggplot2`, which has a nice system for creating plots of each level of a variable without much extra code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(OrchardSprays, aes(treatment, decrease)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~treatment, scales="free_x", ncol=2)
```

To put all the boxplots in a single graph, just remove the last line:

```
ggplot(OrchardSprays, aes(treatment, decrease)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be with how you use `subset`. First, there is no variable named `Site` in the data set. Second, `Site = here_tmp` is not a logical expression.

Assuming you meant `treatment` instead of `Site`, try this:

```
sites <- levels(OrchardSprays$treatment)
par(mfcol=c(4,2))
for (i in 1:length(sites)) {
  here_tmp<-sites[i]
  plot(droplevels(subset(OrchardSprays, treatment == here_tmp, 
       select = c(treatment,decrease))))
}
```

I'm not really sure though if this is your desired outcome because, personally, I don't see a reason to put them in separate plots.

Let me know if this was helpful!

Comment: Thanks a lot That's awesome! Yeah I know it sounds stupid to do this, but I'm not using this database. This was just an example. I'm using multiple sites of study with different species in them and I want to plot them in different graphics rapidly. I might do that a lot of time and with different length of levels. So that's why it's not really looking good with that dataset. 

Thanks again !